# Hide HTML tags in text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a scenario where I use autocomplete jquery UI with textarea. Every time user selects a value from suggestion, textarea is populated with selection followed by a semicolon.

I need to keep track of id's for selected values from the suggestion. My idea was to have them in data attributes of a span tag,wrap selected values in it and populate the textarea.But now textarea is displaying these HTML tags.

Any suggestions on what should be done?

Comment: So like an autocomplete similar to on here when you select the tags for a question. I always just save the IDs in a hidden text field to use upon submission. If needed as well I display some graphic, html, etc to the user so they can see what they picked and remove if necessary. Is that what you mean?

Comment: yes..its for the user and also I can retrieve the id's later. If save to hidden text field then chances are that I lose the mapping between selection and id's here.

Comment: Well that's how I've done it. That way, you are breaking apart the visual aspect of your setup and the data aspect. On the select method of the auto complete I just run my "save to hidden field" function and my "create feedback function". It's seems pretty clean and straight forward to me. I'm not a fan of trying to parse ids and such from injected code.

Comment: so, are you creating a new hidden field for every selection? How are u managing the mapping?

Comment: No I usually store the ids in a comma separated list. So on every `onselect` function from my autocomplete, I check if the data exists in my already selected list. If it doesn't I add it. If it does I do nothing. (I usually hide already selected data from the autocomplete results but just in case I do another check). Its pretty basic. Then on submit or whatever, i just parse my comma separated list.

Comment: I cant do the same here, user doesn't always have to pick from autocomplete..for example think of it like email "to" box where u get suggestions..or u can type in your own..and u can edit the selected value from dropdown..in such cases u'll lose the mapping

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24544/discussion-between-remo-and-leeish)

Comment: Have you tried Chosen.js, they do the selection for you, and you can just create a callback to grab the ids when the form submits. Or upon another action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve this simply and keep your IDs correct *(when you need to leave things open so the user can free type)* is to fetch the IDs when you need them and not before. What I mean is, allow your user to autocomplete and select, or type manually, but then at the point you do something with that data, you then fetch IDs for each item in the list.

```
<textarea>Item 1; Item 2; Manual Item 3;</textarea>
```

Then say at the point of submitting *(or even on the server-side)* you then split your list and do the look up for each ID based on the name. This will automatically protect against a user doing something like manual modification of `Item 1` or say reordering the list:

```
<textarea>Item 42; Item 2; Manual Item 3;</textarea>
```

With the above example, because each item in the list is re-interrogated for it's ID just before you need it, the `Item 42` will be used instead of `Item 1`. If you had any other form of ID tracking you'd have to check for this eventuality anyway, which would lead to a whole heap of extra code and work.

The only extra work you have to do, when checking for IDs at the point of submit, is if you want anything special to happen for items that don't already exist. But then it is most likely you would have needed to do this anyway with a system that specifically tracked the IDs.

If you are worried about optimisation, you can always keep a hash/object using the name as a look-up key and the value as the ID (returned when the user autocompletes). And then use this hash to fill out a list of IDs when the user is finished.

```
/// create your lookup object
lookup = {};

/// store in the lookup
lookup[name] = id;

/// then after a few selections you'll end up with an object like so:
{
  'Item 1': 1,
  'Item 2': 2,
  'Item 42': 42
};
```

Obviously you'll probably want to take into account upper and lower case possibilities of the name, but that can be achieved with `.toLowerCase()`